# Flex vGroup Rotation

Tags: apache-flex, rotation

I am trying to rotate a VGroup so that it aligns parallel to an inclined arrow(which is a custom component)

If, within the component, I use

> this.rotation=20;

then, nothing is displayed on the screen.

I have also tried using the Matrix class, but that also did not work.

Request help

Comment: What content do you use inside your VGroup? Maybe text with system fonts? If so, then it is predictable behavior, because system fonts do not render when rotated.

Comment: yes, there are labels inside, Do I need a font to be embedded?

Comment: Yes. If you will use embedded font, the text content will rotate fine. Otherwise it just disappears.